# SSRS : SQL IF Boolean expression 1 OR Boolean Expression 2 NOT WORKING

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Im working on a SSRS Project and I have 4 parameters which is
@DateFrom,@DateTo,@VhGroup,@Agent. The case is if @Agent OR @VHGroup is equal to '(Blank)' then the else statement will execute. But I cant seem to make it work. Here is the sql statement

```
IF @VHGroup <> '(Blank)' OR @Agent <> '(Blank)'
    SELECT [Call ID of Abandoned]                                                                                               as CallIdAbandoned
    ,[InboundQueue]                                                                                                             as AbandonedCallQueue
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),[OriginalDateTime])                                                                                                           as CallArivalDateTime
    ,[OriginalEndDateTime]                                                                                                      as AbandonedDateTime
    ,[OriginalDuration]                                                                                                         as AbandonedDuration
    ,[CallIDVH]                                                                                                                                             as AgentGroup
    ,CASE WHEN [Outcome] = 'Handled Note : Call Could not be connected' THEN 'Subs Unavailable' ELSE [OutCome] END              as Outcome
    ,[TalkTime]                                                                                                                 as OutBoundDuration
     FROM [AgentStatisticsEOD].[dbo].[VH_Data]
     WHERE CONVERT(Date,[SCBCallDateTimeRequest]) BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo 
     AND [AgentGroup]  collate database_default in (SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@VHGroup,','))
     AND [CallOutAgentName] collate database_default in (SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@Agent,','))
ELSE
    SELECT [Call ID of Abandoned]                                                                                               as CallIdAbandoned
    ,[InboundQueue]                                                                                                             as AbandonedCallQueue
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),[OriginalDateTime])                                                                                                           as CallArivalDateTime
    ,[OriginalEndDateTime]                                                                                                      as AbandonedDateTime
    ,[OriginalDuration]                                                                                                         as AbandonedDuration
    ,[CallIDVH]                                                                                                                                                 as AgentGroup
    ,CASE WHEN [Outcome] = 'Handled Note : Call Could not be connected' THEN 'Subs Unavailable' ELSE [OutCome] END              as Outcome
    ,[TalkTime]                                                                                                                 as OutBoundDuration
     FROM [AgentStatisticsEOD].[dbo].[VH_Data]
     WHERE CONVERT(Date,[SCBCallDateTimeRequest]) BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo
     AND [AgentGroup]  collate database_default in (SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@VHGroup,','))
     OR [CallOutAgentName] collate database_default in (SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@Agent,','))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Where is this code? in a query source?  The two sides of the else appear to be identical so how can you tell they 'don't work' (please explain 'don't work). Do you have an explicit choiec ' (blank) in your parameters? You might need `''` or `NULL`

Comment: if I try the parameter @Agent = '(Blank)' the statement returns nothing.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no they are not. They difference is the "AND" and "OR" in the filter.

Comment: Ah I missed that. You _probably_ want brackets around the two OR terms in the second one then. Regardless, this isn't a good pattern. You should write _one_ SQL statement and incorporate the optional logic in the `where` clause.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid what is the other way then?

Comment: I'll post an answer but I'm not certain what you are trying to do. This is all just a matter of understanding boolean logic

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that's why I tried this method because I cant think of anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your exact logic here but this approach requires less repeated code:

In this query, if either parameter is blank it won't filter on it at all.

Just be absolutely certain that the parameter value is truly `(Blank)` (not `''` or `NULL`)

```
    SELECT [Call ID of Abandoned]                                                                                               as CallIdAbandoned
    ,[InboundQueue]                                                                                                             as AbandonedCallQueue
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),[OriginalDateTime])                                                                                                           as CallArivalDateTime
    ,[OriginalEndDateTime]                                                                                                      as AbandonedDateTime
    ,[OriginalDuration]                                                                                                         as AbandonedDuration
    ,[CallIDVH]                                                                                                                                             as AgentGroup
    ,CASE WHEN [Outcome] = 'Handled Note : Call Could not be connected' THEN 'Subs Unavailable' ELSE [OutCome] END              as Outcome
    ,[TalkTime]                                                                                                                 as OutBoundDuration
     FROM [AgentStatisticsEOD].[dbo].[VH_Data]
     WHERE CONVERT(Date,[SCBCallDateTimeRequest]) BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo 
     AND 
     (
        @VHGroup = '(Blank)' 
        OR 
        [AgentGroup]  collate database_default in (
            SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@VHGroup,',')
        )
     )
     AND
     (
        @Agent = '(Blank)'
        OR
        [CallOutAgentName] collate database_default in (
           SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@Agent,',')
        )
     )
```

Comment: So I guess this will be faster query than my query? It works amazingly.

Comment: just one more question before I accept your answer. What would be the difference if I do this Agent = Agent and I didn't quite get the sense of Agent = '(Blank)' What is their difference.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. If you put `Agent=Agent` in that code somewhere (where would you put it?!) it would fail because you don't have a column called `Agent`. If you mean `@Agent=@Agent`... whats the point? It's always true.

Comment: yeah I was talking about the variable. Can you elaborate what is the meaning of this condition `@VHGroup = '(Blank)' 
        OR 
        [AgentGroup]  collate database_default in (
            SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@VHGroup,',')`

Comment: It's just a logical statement that evaluates to true or false. If @VHGroup is indeed (Blank) then it evaluates to: `TRUE OR [AgentGroup] collate database_default in ( SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit(@VHGroup,',')`. Note that TRUE OR _anything_ is _always_ TRUE. It's a way of 'short circuiting' logical terms. If I understand your intention correctly, having a parameter=(Blank) means you don't want to filter in that parameter at all, which is what that statement does. If the value is blank it 'short circuits' that to true.

Comment: It helps to work through it, setting the parameter value. If it's (blank) it becomes `'(Blank)' = '(Blank)' OR [AgentGroup] collate database_default in ( SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit('(Blank)',',')` which evaluates to `TRUE OR (probably) FALSE` which is always TRUE

Comment: In fact this query _could_ be slower due to something called parameter sniffing. But it is less maintenance because if you want to add a column you only need to add it in one spot. Parameter sniffing is a whole other thing.

Comment: so in short explanation. Once the `@VHGroup = '(Blank)'` it will skip the `[AgentGroup] collate database_default in ( SELECT value from dbo.FnSplit('(Blank)',',')`

Comment: Well.... it won't literally skip anything. It'll still evaluate it. It's just the outcome doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You logic is wrong, the `IF` statement should be using `AND` like this:

```
IF @VHGroup <> '(Blank)' AND @Agent <> '(Blank)'
    --snip
ELSE
    --snip
```

Comment: No, I need "OR" because if either VHGroup or Agent is equal to (Blank) the else statement should execute.

Comment: Weird. How that worked? because as far as I know. AND needs both boolean expression to be true and OR needs either one of the two to be true.

Comment: Because you are using `<>` not `=`

Comment: Exactly, but the logic says "if vhgroup is not blank and agent is not blank"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid oh my god I get it. Thanks